# How can I use Regular Expression to replace &#098; with respective ascii character?

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I wrote a VB .Net application that asks the user for a URL, then the application will pull the HTML content of that URL and filters out most stuff except for anything between `<td> </td>` tags.

So if the HTML of that url is something like this

`<html><body><table><tr><td>My content here</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>`

then the application will simply print out:
`My content here`

However, the problem is some URLs have populated these `<td></td>` with the ascii codes of the letters rather than letters themselves, so here is an example:

`<html><body><table><tr><td>">&#098;&#097;&#110;&#100;&#105;&#116;&#032;&#097;&#116;</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>`

so my program will display:

```
'&#098;&#097;&#110;&#100;&#105;&#116;'
```

but any browser will display the above as

```
bandit
```

I tried to use RegEx to replace those numbers to their respective characters (using 'Chr' function), but I failed.
Here is what I tried:

```
Me.TextBox3.Text = Regex.Replace(htmlDoc, "&#\d\d\d;", chr("$&"))
```

but that presents an error.

My question is: how can I replace all occurences of `&#\d\d\d;` with `Chr(value of the \d\d\d that was matched earlier)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one can be achieved easily....by using the HTMLDecode method.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd2251d-1359-49ce-b6a2-7ca492d560a5/converting-nbsp-when-using-serverurldecode?forum=csharpgeneral

```
string subject = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["subject"]));
```

this is c#, but you can easily convert this to vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode html into plain string.